# jQuery UI Icons for Mac Retina

Tags: jquery-ui, retina-display

Has anybody ran into a way to fix the pixelated jQuery UI Icons on the new MacBook Pro with the Retina display? I've been searching for an @2x solution but as of yet haven't found one.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is a projects which aims to make jQueryUI compatible to Twitter Bootstrap (and therefor with FontAwesome), see: https://github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap/

It should be possible to extract the FontAwesome UI parts without using TBS.